# Не отображается текст на картинке System.Drawing.Common. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, графика

Я использую Linux (KDE neon) x64.
Есть переменная с текстом.
К примеру, если в ней содержатся такие символы: "      " то на картинке ничего не отображается (полностью чёрная).
А если нет (пример: "one. один"), то отлично работает.

Для рендера текста на картинке я использую такой код ->

```
            string text = "Текст";
            using (Bitmap MainPicture = new Bitmap(1000, 500, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
            using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(MainPicture))
            using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
                graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, FillRectangle);

                Console.WriteLine("TEXT: " + text);
                // Draw text
                graph.DrawString("\"" + text + "\"", font, Brushes.White, TextRectangle, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

                MainPicture.Save(resultPicturePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }
```

Как заставить рендерить такие символы??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67138869/1988244 - может грабли с libgdiplus?